# Penalty Parameters Semi-Global Matching with "disparity" function of Computer Vision toolbox

Tags: matlab, disparity-mapping

Does anybody know the values of the penalty parameters in smoothness constrain of the [Semi-Global Matching](https://www.robotic.de/fileadmin/robotic/hirschmu/cvpr05hh.pdf) (SGM) technique used by the [disparity](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/disparity.html?searchHighlight=disparity&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) function of Matlabs Computer Vision?

In the documentation they refer the SGM paper (see links). In the SGM two penalty parameters (P1 and P2) are defined in Equation 11. I would like to know the set values of these parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I found the parameters in the source code of the function.

```
P1 = 8 * (blocksize)^2
P2 = 32 * (blocksize)^2
```